# axios get string and patch as object from the same input vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, axios

I have a table that I get the `userList` as props and render it into the table with `v-for="(user , index) in userList" :key="index"`  and as string `:value="user.username"` but now my swagger API needs me to patch it as an object of s.th like `username:{value: "", operand: 1}`
does anyone know how am I supposed to change the data type and send it as formData to my axios patch?
my axios.patch was also like this before i find out I need an object to pass :')

```
async userEdit(id) {
      const response = await this.$store.dispatch('axiosPatch', {url: `/employees/${id}`,
        formData: {
          username: this.username.value,
          email: this.email,
          mobile: this.mobile,
        }
    }, this.$data)
   },
```

my input form is also like this:

```
<input type="text" class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0 text-center
                  border-0 bg-white w-100 p-1"
        :disabled="!user.disabled"
        :value="user.nationalCode">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare an object variable in the data part and then assign items to it for example we have `items` object defined in data then we have `items.username`,`items.email`, and so on, at the end when you want to send this object to the server, you could convert all of these by doing a for loop on it. for example:

```js
let dataToPatch = [];
let items = {username:'Ali',email:'test@test.com'};
for(item in items){
  const newItem = {};
  newItem[item] ={value:items[item],operand: 1};
  dataToPatch.push(newItem);
}

console.log(dataToPatch)
```

Comment: then how am I supposed to use it in v-model? just like normal => v-model="user.username" or v-model="items.username" ?

Comment: absolutely like this `items.username`

Comment: umm yeah I've got that... but it gets an error that I can't use v-model when binding :value=""

Comment: yes you can use one of them, v-model or value